# Prevent Moment js guessing year when the year set as the year 20

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am using moment js and want to check the year the user has entered in the input box. My code looks like this.

```
const year = moment('10/12/20', 'DD/MM/YYYY').format("YYYY");
```

`year` is being returning year as `2020` as opposed to `0020`. Does anyone know how to prevent moment from being 'too clever'?

I am using version `"moment": "2.17.1"`. Also, may be related to this [issue](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/3842).

[It seems to work here so may be a version issue.](http://jsfiddle.net/T5VLG/300/)

Comment: Shouldn't the `.format()` be `'YY'`? Currently you're clearly asking for a 4-character year.

Comment: pass in '10/12/0020'

Comment: @VergilPenkov check it out here though - http://jsfiddle.net/T5VLG/300/. It works. As it is based on user input it updates on each keystroke so thats why i am hoping to not have to add in '0's

Comment: @john the issue is that it is the user will be inputting the year so will change on each input. So on the first time I will be checking for `Y` then, `YY`, then `YYY`... make sense?

Comment: @VergilPenkov if you use `YY` ... 0-70 will become 2000-2070 and 71-99 will become 1971-1999 ... no possibility of any year outside the range 1971-2070 is then possible - question clearly asks how to allow a year of 0020

Comment: On the newer version this problem persists. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/0gqk0mbu/ with the new version. Bug is there.

Comment: @john i updated the question. I am looking for `0020` . apologies if it was unclear. Moment js returns 2020. see here http://jsfiddle.net/0gqk0mbu/

Comment: use `'DD/MM/Y'` - http://jsfiddle.net/0gqk0mbu/2/

Comment: hmmm ... the 19/20 century cutoff used to be 68/69 ... so a 2 digit year would be 1969->2068 ... then in version 2.0.0 it was as I said above, 1971->2070 ... and at some point after 2.0.0 it reverted back to 1969->2068 again - not important to this question - just putting it out there for accuracy with respect to my previous comment :p

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks for your help with this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the year token consisting of a single Y like here:

```
const year = moment('10/12/20', 'DD/MM/Y').format("YYYY");
```

From the [momentjs documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/):

> `YYYY` from version 2.10.5 supports 2 digit years, and converts them to
>   a year near 2000 (same as `YY`).
>
> `Y` was added in 2.11.1. It will match any number, signed or unsigned.
>   It is useful for years that are not 4 digits or are before the common
>   era. It can be used for any year.